# XP bars in Google Sheets. how to make it overflow into new bar? (SPARKLINE)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[image: screenshot]

I'm trying to gamify my studies and I'm using XP bars to do that. It's a way of tracking and seeing progress.

I have Multiple bars, but I want the bars to fill up sequentially,

```
level 1 - 0-100
level 2 - 100-200
level 3 - 200-300
```

and so on.

currently using this line to create the bar:

```
=SPARKLINE(I52,{"charttype","bar";"max",100;"color1","[color]";"empty","zero"})
```

In my mind, I think I would need to repace the 100 with some sort of "between" statement, but I have no idea how to do that. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set the MAX depends on your goal. The only problem with SPARKLINE:BAR, you can't change the MIN Value. It's set to 0.

[MAX SPARKLINE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHpSQ.png)

Consider using COLUMN instead and it will look like a battery filling your progress. Just create a MIN and MAX column then set them to negative to start the column from the top of the cell.

> =SPARKLINE(-$H$1,{"charttype","column";"ymin",-N3;"ymax",-M3;"color","#35c390"})

[SPARKLINE:COLUMN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnVCs.png)